# SqlClient not supported on this platform

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, azure-functions, sqlclient

I have a project for Azure Functions that has .net standard 2.0 as target framework. This project uses System.Data.Sqlclient to insert and fetch data from a db. It works fine when I deploy it to azure.

To be able to test my code I have created classes in this project that handle the business logic and is setup in the static function that azure executes.

My problem is that when I try to create a class library that is to contain unit tests, I always get an exception that says: System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform. The code runs fine before that. I have tried both .net core and .net 4.6.1 as target framework but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I created a new class library with .net core 2 as target. Don't know why it didn't work the first time so unfortunately I cannot tell what went wrong the first time.